# REST API - Benefit of adding extra layer

Tags: cloud, microservices, distributed-system, system-design

What would be the benefit of adding this "Microservice" extra layer, between Python script and REST API endpoint?

The user is running the Python script. And it is given that the Python script is able to access "Cloud REST API" endpoint, and perform a request. So why do we need this microservice component in the middle?

I'll will write here what I think the Advantages and Disadvantages of this extra layer, please let me know if you can think of some other reasons:

**Advantages:**

- Might be able to do some processing on the response in microservice layer (but should be possible in Python as well no?)
- We can scale up and add another instace of "microservice" at peek time (but is it matter? Cloud will have to handle all the requests either way)

**Disadvantages:**

- Adding extra layer, might be a single point of failure if down, although "Cloud" is up.
- Another hop, which might slow down the process of getting response back to the client.

[image]

Comment: if this microservice is only working as a proxy then there is no advantage other than acting as a proxy